# Datetime format automatically changed by Create Item sharepoint block in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

How to store the datetime in ISO format as a string in SharePoint list using logic apps. Eg: If my date is "2023-03-01T10:20:30Z" or "2023-03-01T10:20:30+01:00", the create item block in logic app is converting the datetime string to "03/01/2023 10:20:30" or "03/01/2023 01:20:30".

Tried in Logic Apps. I want to store it as is i.e. "2023-03-01T10:20:30Z" or "2023-03-01T10:20:30+01:00" in SharePoint through Logic App.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwn0H.jpg)

Comment: Show us with screenshots and how you’re applying that. Pretty hard to help without more info.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want the output to be same as Input.

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get this by updating the item after creation. I have replaced `/` with `-`, a blank space with `T` and concatenated `Z` in the end. Below is the logic app flow that worked for me.

[image]

Below is the expression that I used

```
concat(replace(replace(body('Create_item')['Title'],'/','-'),' ','T'),'Z')
```

Results:

[image]